# Confusion while working with lists and the "new" parameter

Tags: c#, list, object

Well, i am new to C# and it seems that i got a problem right over here. I know the problem already, but I don't know how to solve it. I am simply overwriting the object i want to add to my list. Can anyone help me?

```
List<string> dataSet = new List<string>();
string s;
while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        if (s[0] == '$')
        {
            dataSet.Add(s);
            if (s.Contains("GPGGA"))
            {
                myData.Add(new DataSet(dataSet));
                dataSet.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Please elaborate on what value is overwritten and what is it you are trying to do.

Comment: when i add a second dataset to my list called "myData" it overwrites all existing data, so only the latest and x copies of it are in my list

Comment: What is the type of mydata ? One thing I noticed is you are clearing dataSet in if block after you do mydata.Add. Not sure if that correct logic but that surely will clear your dataset and you will have the latest added value (s) only at the end of while loop.

Comment: Also I don't think DataSet supports this constructor.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx

Comment: Was adding the list to the myData the problem? or was it just that the values in dataSet is being lost?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly your adding a list of strings to a dataset.  You are then clearing that list.  It looks to me that your adding a reference to a list, then your calling clear on that list.  That is why your loosing your values.  You need to add a copy of that list to the other dataset.  Try the code below

```
List<string> dataSet = new List<string>();
string s;
while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        if (s[0] == '$')
        {
            dataSet.Add(s);
            if (s.Contains("GPGGA"))
            {
                myData.Add(new DataSet(dataSet.ToList()));
                dataSet.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

dataSet.ToList() will return a copy of the List instead of adding a reference to it, that way dataSet.Clear() won't clear the list you added to myData

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the problems you may be having is that you've confused yourself a little by naming your `List<T>` a keyword.  A `DataSet` is its own thing and makes this code very hard to read.   First, let's clean that up:

```
List<string> theData = new List<string>();
string s;
while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        if (s[0] == '$')
        {
            theData.Add(s);
            if (s.Contains("GPGGA"))
            {
                myData.Add(new DataSet(theData)); //you're passing your source by reference.
                theData.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to pass the value of your datasource, but a `List<T>` is a reference type.

```
List<string> theData = new List<string>();
    string s;
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            if (s[0] == '$')
            {
                theData.Add(s);
                if (s.Contains("GPGGA"))
                {
                    List<string> bindingdata = theData.ToList();
                    myData.Add(new DataSet(bindingData)); //you're passing
                    //your source by value, because it's using a new list.
                    theData.Clear(); //you can now safely do this.
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All of that done, it still won't work, because `DataSet` doesn't have a constructor that accepts a `List<string>`.  You need to change `myData.Add(new DataSet(theData))` to the actual constructor.  Interestingly, your `DataSet` may be the poor choice for what you're doing here.  Unless you are using multiple tables, which you don't appear to be, you're better off using just one `DataTable`.

```
List<string> theData = new List<string>();
    string s;
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            if (s[0] == '$')
            {
                theData.Add(s);
                if (s.Contains("GPGGA"))
                {   //we don't need this now.
                    //List<string> bindingdata = theData.ToList();
//make myData a DataSet so you can use datatables
// instead of attempting IEnumerable<DataSet>

                    DataTable foo = new DataTable("Foo");                               
                    foreach(string s in theData)
                    { 
                        var y = foo.NewRow();
                        y[0] = s;
                        foo.Rows.Add(y);
                    }
                    myData.Add(foo);                                
                    theData.Clear(); //you can now safely do this.
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Even with all of that, you'd be saving yourself a lot of trouble if you look into the `DataTable` and `StringBuilder` classes.  There are better ways to do all of this than you're attempting.

Comment: Have you tested this - as DataSet doesn't appear to have a constructor that takes a list as a parameter.

Comment: I noticed the weird constructor after I posted, so I went back and corrected it and supplemented the answer.

Comment: I didnt know that DataSet is  a predefined class, i write my own DataSet class which does completely different things

Comment: Take a look at this article:https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-discouraged-to-reinvent-the-wheel-in-programming

Comment: Then look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Michael: It would be useful to see the constructor for your DataSet. Just as a thought - when you add to a list you are adding a reference to the existing object, instead of using dataset.Clear() you could try dataset = new DataSet() so you create a new DataSet & the original one is now referenced in the list.